# Setting duration to scrollTop()

Tags: jquery, html

i just wish to give the scrollTop a duration or time to scroll to 0 position. and not just scroll to the top immediately like some kind of animating it. Here is my code feel free to look into it. Thanks in advance as i await your response.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  $("#upup").on("click", function() {
    $("body").scrollTop(5);
  });
},6000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="upup">scroll up baby</button>
```

Comment: You have misunderstood the `setTimeout()`

Comment: Not exactly getting the issue do you want to click the button after sometime of want to scroll after sometime of click the button

Comment: just trying to know if it works out

Comment: Non-jQuery solution discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478645/3556531

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the example,

```
$("#upup").on("click", function() {
 $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: 0
 }, 6000);
});
```

Working [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rjpycud4/)

Hope helps,

Comment: Yeah thanks man, it is pretty working. Ja bless hoping to know you more

Answer (score 2):

Use scroll with  animation() .

```js
$("#upup").on("click", function() {
   $("body").stop().animate({scrollTop:0}, 1000, 'linear', function() { 
     alert("Finished ");
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  position:relative;
height:1000px;
}
#upup{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  right:0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
Scroll down

</div>
<button id="upup">scroll up baby</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `animate()` to scroll.

**EDIT :** Using the css idea to expand content by [xyz](/users/7011496/xyz)

```js
$("#upup").on("click", function() {
     $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, 6000);
});
```

```css
body{
  position:relative;
  height:800px;
}
button{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello</div>
<button id="upup">scroll up baby</button>
```