# How to animate window.scrollTo with Javascript NOT jQuery?

Tags: javascript

I have searched and although writers has written in `JavaScript` people answer for jQuery. Anyway, How can I animate `window.scrollTo` with JavaScript? I used `setInterval` but not worked. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I found it, By passing this object, Scroll smoothly :

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: selectedFrame.offsetTop,
  left: 0,
  behavior: 'smooth'
});
```

Note : `smooth` is not supported in Safari.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTo

Comment: behaviour `smooth` is not supported in safari

Comment: @charlesokojie You could use a polyfill if you wanted: https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=smoothscroll%2Cwindow.scroll

Comment: Now supported by Safari (v14) - tested using v17 on macOS

Answer (score 8):

try this one.

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

I have used this to scroll from bottom to top. And it works for me using javascript.

Another way :

**HTML**

```
<button onclick="scrollToTop(3000);"></button>
```

**Javascript**

```
 function scrollToTop(scrollDuration) {
  var scrollStep = -window.scrollY / (scrollDuration / 15),
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
    if ( window.scrollY != 0 ) {
        window.scrollBy( 0, scrollStep );
    }
    else clearInterval(scrollInterval); 
 },15);
}
```

Comment: But that just jumps. OP wants to animate the scrolling.

Comment: @SachinShah Myself have written that I'm using `window.scrollTo`, But animating is a problem.

Comment: @AliBahaari I have update my answer. Please try this.

Comment: @SachinShah I think it just goes to top, I don't need just going up, I have different values.

Comment: @AliBahaari Can you please re frame your need in details ?

Comment: @SachinShah I'm writing a plugin and I need to give `window.scrollTo` different  values, I have done this but I just need to do it by animation.

Comment: @AliBahaari Different values means to pass X and Y values ?

Comment: @SachinShah Just Y

Comment: Elegant solution! Quick question: why are you dividing `scrollDuration` by `15`? Is it okay to call it a `smoothness` factor or variable (specified in millisecond)?

Answer (score 0):

This way worked for me:

```
function slideTo(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    document.body.scrollTo({
        top: element.offsetTop,
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a very fancy scroll using @SachinShah's answer above for my custom needs.

Might come in handy to someone.

But first let me tell you what it does. It

- scrolls to a specified element's id
- follows a specified duration
- can offset the target. Comes in handy when working with sticky/smart headers
- control smoothness of scroll/setInterval function

Keep in mind that

- Relative scrolling method `window.scrollBy` is used, hence scrollDirection (up/down) needs to be determined in the logic
- scrollDuration and scrollSmoothness are in milliSeconds

```
/**
 * Scroll to the top of the page in a specified duration(ms) and smoothness(ms)
 * ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52478645/3556531
 * @param {String} elementID
 * @param {Int} scrollDuration
 * @param {Int} offset
 * @param {Int} scrollSmoothness
 */

const fancyAScroll = (
  elementID = 'main-content',
  scrollDuration = 500,
  offset = 0, // I  had to use 120 to compensate for a sticky header
  scrollSmoothness = 10
) => {
  const accuracyBuffer = 10
  try {

    // #1 Calculate the final offset position to scroll-to
    const element = document?.getElementById(elementID)
    const bodyRect = document?.body?.getBoundingClientRect().top
    const elementRect = element?.getBoundingClientRect().top
    const elementPosition = elementRect - bodyRect
    const offsetPosition = elementPosition - offset // final - target position to scroll

    // #2 calculate steps & direction (up or down)
    const scrollStepUnit = offsetPosition / (scrollDuration / scrollSmoothness)
    const scrollStepDirection = offsetPosition > window?.scrollY ? '' : '-'
    const scrollStepY = `${scrollStepDirection}${scrollStepUnit}`

    // #3 keep on relatively scrolling untill reached to the destination
    const scrollInterval = setInterval(() => {
      let targetRangeReached =
        offsetPosition - accuracyBuffer < window.scrollY &&
        window.scrollY < offsetPosition + accuracyBuffer

      targetRangeReached ? clearInterval(scrollInterval) : window.scrollBy(0, scrollStepY)
    }, scrollSmoothness)
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.error('Error @scrollTopWithDuration\n', error)
  }
}

export default fancyAScroll
```

Comment: window.scrollIntoView also does pretty much the same but without customization option for the duration.